# How to implement ListFragment and NavigationDrawerFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to build an android application with a Fragment which contains a List of Option and if I click on one of this option, I can see, another fragment with other option.

So I build this:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="480dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_list"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#6dc659"
            android:foreground="@color/white">
        </ListView>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:name="it.eresult.decipher.fragment.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks{

    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private ListView leftList;
    private String[] leftListStrings;
    private String[] rightListStrings;
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        leftList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_list);

        leftListStrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.principal_menu);

        leftList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,leftListStrings));

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        leftList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {


                arg1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.selected_menu_option));

                if(arg2 == 0){


                }

            }

        });

        drawer.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View arg0, float arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //rightList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        //TODO

    }

    class MayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        List<String> myList = null;
        public MayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource,  objects);
            myList = objects;
        }
        public List<String> getMyList() {
            return myList;
        }
        public void setMyList(List<String> myList) {
            this.myList = myList;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("omnia");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is NavigationDrawerFragment.java

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {


    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;
    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    Toolbar toolBar;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        }


        // Select the default item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // the fragment has menu items to contribute
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.social_history),
                        getString(R.string.encounter),
                        getString(R.string.problems),
                }));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }


    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        //mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),
                mDrawerLayout,
                null,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }
                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }
                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };


        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

With this code, if I try to run my application, I can see the complete menu like this

[image]

Instead, I want to see only the left menu, and if I click on one items, see the right menu